# Save the id of ajax call to use it in the return function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this code to populate the option in my select box(i have 7 select box in this page) with json response from the server(ajax)

```
for (j=1; j <= 7; j++){

            $.getJSON('mobile_json.php', {id:j}, function(data) {
                var select = $('#userAccess' + j);              
                var options = select.attr('options');
                $.each(data, function(index, array) {                   
                    options[array['Id']] = new Option(array['Name']);
                });  
            });  
    }
```

The problem is after the calling to the ajax, the `j` equal to `8` ,
what i want is when the function deal with the json array, is set it to the right select box  like : userAccess1 , userAccess2 ... userAccess7,

how can i deal with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are creating closures in a loop. [This helped me to understand it better](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html) (especially example 5).

One way to solve this is to create an anonymous function and execute it immediately :

```
for (j=1; j <= 7; j++){
    (function(index) {
        $.getJSON('mobile_json.php', {id:index}, function(data) {
            var select = $('#userAccess' + index);              
            var options = select.attr('options');
            $.each(data, function(index, array) {                   
                options[array['Id']] = new Option(array['Name']);
            });  
        });
     })(j)
 }
```

This "captures" the current value of `j`. If you don't do this, by the time the closure (the callback function to the Ajax request) is executed, the loop is already finished, leaving `j` with the value of `8`.
That's the tricky thing about closures :)